# How to count based on value in observation in SAS

Tags: sas

I hope this message finds you well. I am very new to SAS programming and I am trying to create some code that counts number of unique entries in multiple columns for several observations. I also have columns in between that I would like to disregard. Below is an example dataset:

```
|ID |   Var1   |   NotNeededVar2   |   Var3   |   Var4   |   Var5   |
| 1 | String1  |  StringSomething  |  String2 |  String3 |  String3 |
| 2 | String1  |  StringSomething  |  String2 |  String1 |  String2 |
| 3 | String1  |  StringSomething  |  String1 |  String1 |  String1 |
| 4 | String1  |  StringSomething  |     .    |  String2 |  String2 |
```

The desired outcome is a new dataset with a newly added column containing the count of unique entries of columns 1, 3, 4 and 5:

```
|ID |   Var1   |   NotNeededVar2   |   Var3   |   Var4   |   Var5   | Unique(Var1, 3, 4, 5) |
| 1 | String1  |  StringSomething  |  String2 |  String3 |  String3 |        3           |
| 2 | String1  |  StringSomething  |  String2 |  String1 |  String2 |        2           |
| 3 | String1  |  StringSomething  |  String1 |  String1 |  String1 |        1           |
| 4 | String1  |  StringSomething  |     .    |  String2 |  String2 |        2           |
```

So far all I can think of is using multiple if/then statements to test if the columns are unique and not missing, but this seems like a sure way to make some errors and make it very complicated.

Any and all help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: Changed the example to reflect string/character values rather than numeric values. Not sure if it makes a difference or not, but this is closer to my actual situation.

EDIT2: Inserted unwanted column to better reflect my dataset.

Comment: Do you have only three columns? Will that expand?

Comment: I do have more columns. I have a total of four columns I want to take into account. I also have columns in between that I would like to disregard, which I am just now realizing may make it a bit more difficult. I have updated the example.

Comment: Why not just transpose the data?  Then a simple sql query with `count(distinct var)` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the WHICHC() function to check if the current value appears earlier in the list.

```
data have ;
  input ID (Var1 NotNeededVar2 Var3 Var4 Var5) (:$20.);
cards;
1 String1 StringSomething String2 String3 String3  
2 String1 StringSomething String2 String1 String2  
3 String1 StringSomething String1 String1 String1  
4 String1 StringSomething    .    String2 String2  
5 . . . . .
;

data want;
  set have;
  array list var1 var3-var5 ;
  count=0;
  do index=1 to dim(list);
   if not missing(list[index]) and whichc(list[index],of list[*])=index then count+1;
  end;
  drop index;
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    ID     Var1       NotNeededVar2      Var3       Var4       Var5      count

 1      1    String1    StringSomething    String2    String3    String3      3
 2      2    String1    StringSomething    String2    String1    String2      2
 3      3    String1    StringSomething    String1    String1    String1      1
 4      4    String1    StringSomething               String2    String2      2
 5      5                                                                     0
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thank a lot. I clearly need to learn more about arrays it seems, as both the suggested answers are based on this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume the order of the variables aren't important. If they are, you need to copy them to a different array first and then sort through this.

```
data want;
set have;

array _myvars(*) var1 var3 var4 var5;

*sorts arrays values alphabetically - you may not want this step;
call sortc(of _myvars(*));

count = 0;

do i=2 to dim(_myvars);
    if _myvars(i) ne _myvars(i-1) then count+1;
end;

run;
```